# Set property value on mongoose result not working in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hullo,

I'm receiving a MongoDB object from a `findById`, and I'd like to convert the `_id` in that object from the `ObjectID` type to a `string`.
I'm doing something wrong, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is!
I've created the following function:

```
    student: async (parent, { _id }, context, info) => {
        var student = await Student.findById(_id);
        student._id = student._id.toString();
        return student.toObject();
    },
```

Using the debugger, I can see all the values are as expected, and `student._id.toString()` is correctly generating a string.
However, the value in the student object is not being set to the generated string.
I've tried adding an intermediate variable `s` to see if that makes a difference and it does not.

What could I be doing wrong here?
What should I do to further debug?

Thank you from a confused C++ developer!

Comment: can you post the result of `console.dir(student)` after the `student._id = student._id.toString();` line? :)

Comment: or maybe do the `student.set(_id, student._id.toString())` and check what happens

Comment: Would `return { ...student, id: id.toString() };` work?

Comment: This is what I get after the set operation as it is now.  I'll try the other suggestions right away.


```
model {$__: InternalCache, isNew: false, errors: undefined, _doc: Object, $init: true}
__v:0
_doc:Object {_id: ObjectID, name: "FirstStudent", __v: 0}
_id:ObjectID
    _bsontype:"ObjectID"
    _id:ObjectID
    generationTime:1543427746
    id:Buffer(12) [91, 254, 214, …]
    $init:true
    errors:undefined
    id:"5bfed6a2a924243518954971"
    isNew:false
    name:"FirstStudent"
```

Comment: `.set` does not work.  However, `return { ...student, _id: student._id.toString() }` does work.  

Why? :D

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I'm far off here, but it looks like it's coming in as an object in the first place because of the curly braces surrounding _id. 
If you remove that you might get what you need.

Other than that, you can try

```
student._id = JSON.stringify(student._id);
```

considering it should be coming back as JSON from your MongoDB

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the trick.  The value is still a bsontype after this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do `_id.toString()`? Mongoose [document has id](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-id) which is the string representation of the `_id`:

```
student: async (parent, { _id }, context, info) => {
   var student = await Student.findById(_id);
   return { id: student.id, ...student }
},
```

Also `toObject` [accepts a transform function](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) which as shown you can set on your schema so that you get the `_id` to behave like the `id` when `toObject` is called.

**Also please note**:

When you get a result from `mongoose` you get your data **wrapped** in a `model` object and your actual document is under the `_doc` property. So when you do your `student._id = student._id.toString()` you are decorating the `model` object and **not** the document. This is why the transform function makes more sense. Otherwise you have to decorate the `_doc` object which gets ugly really.

Comment: That removes a function call, which is great, but iIs using `return { _id: foo, ...student }` considered OK Javascript code?  How would I set the value of `_id` in the middle of a function?

Comment: Just define your `transform` function on your `Student` schema and in there massage the record any shape you want your `toObject` to return. That way all you would need to do it just call `toObject` and that would be all.

Comment: Updated with that answer as well.

Comment: OK, sorry, but I'm really not sure I can live with this solution.  Overshadowing the value rather than changing it seems absurd and messy.  How would I actually change it, for future reference?

Comment: Then again, I understand that when programming in Javascript sometimes the only solution is to hack things together.  Is this one of those times when there's nothing resembling a graceful solution?

Comment: How is this solution a `hack`? By default mongoose gives you the model and via `toObject` you get the document. Since that document value is not as per your high `C++` standards then simply transform it with the `transform` function in your schema. You position towards JS seems quite condescending IMO.

Comment: The result from `mongoose` is wrapped in a `model`, but when accessing a value `_id` the value can't actually be overwritten using a set function.  How is mongoose hiding the value such that it can't be modified?  Looking at the source, `_id` seems to be expected to be a value of type `any`, not a callable unit.  Calling a transform function seems like an obfuscation and a costly alternative to setting a value in an object.